# Random exclamation marks in email body generated using UTL_SMTP in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When i am generating a table of values and writing the output as an email body using UTL_SMTP in pl-sql.

the table generated consistos of 5 columns and 29 rows.

Problem is some random exclamatory marks ! are being generated in the email body.

Code is as follows....

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APPS.xxjdsu_crm_jobs_monitoring(
                                                   errbuf       OUT   VARCHAR2,
                                                   retcode      OUT   VARCHAR2,
                                                   p_subject             IN VARCHAR2,
                                                   P_recipient_to_list   IN VARCHAR2,
                                                   P_recipient_cc_list   IN VARCHAR2,
                                                   p_signature1          IN VARCHAR2,
                                                   p_signature2          IN VARCHAR2,
                                                   p_signature3          IN VARCHAR2,
                                                   p_signature4          IN VARCHAR2
                                                   )
AS
  l_recipient_to_list VARCHAR2(32767) :=lower(replace(P_recipient_to_list,';',','));
  l_recipient_cc_list VARCHAR2(32767) :=lower(replace(P_recipient_cc_list,';',','));
  l_Mail_Conn utl_smtp.Connection;
  l_Mail_Host   VARCHAR2(100) := 'localhost';
  l_From        VARCHAR2(80) ;
  l_Recipient   VARCHAR2(3000);
  l_run_date    DATE := sysdate;
  l_Subject     VARCHAR2(1000) ;
  l_priority    VARCHAR2(10) := 'NORMAL';
  l_instance    VARCHAR2(80);
  l_crlf        VARCHAR2(2) := chr(13)||chr(10);
  l_msg_body    clob := empty_clob;               --This LOB will be the email message
  l_msg_data    VARCHAR2(32767) :=null;
  l_msg_tail    VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_signature   VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_job_status  VARCHAR2(30) := null;
  l_bg_colour   VARCHAR2(80):= null;
  l_schedule    NUMBER :=0;
  l_rp          NUMBER :=1;
  l_rp1         NUMBER :=1;
  j             NUMBER :=0;
   CURSOR cur_req_list_data IS
   (SELECT rownum,
       c.PROGRAM_NAME,
       c.LAST_RUN_REQUEST_ID,
       c.LAST_RUNDATE,
       c.RESULT
FROM ((SELECT fcv.user_concurrent_program_name "PROGRAM_NAME",
       fcr.request_id "LAST_RUN_REQUEST_ID",
       TO_CHAR(fcr.actual_completion_date,' DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "LAST_RUNDATE" ,
       DECODE(fcr.phase_code,
                             'C','Completed',fcr.phase_code)||'/'||DECODE(fcr.status_code,
                                                                                          'C', 'Normal',
                                                                                          'D', 'Cancelled',
                                                                                          'E','Errored',
                                                                                          'F','Scheduled',
                                                                                          'G', 'Warning',fcr.status_code) "RESULT"
       FROM apps.fnd_concurrent_programs_vl fcv,apps.fnd_concurrent_requests fcr
       WHERE user_concurrent_program_name IN ( SELECT fvv.description
                                               FROM apps.fnd_lookup_types_vl ftv,
                                                    apps.fnd_lookup_values_vl fvv
                                               WHERE ftv.lookup_type = fvv.lookup_type
                                               AND ftv.lookup_type LIKE 'CRM_JOBS'
                                               AND fvv.tag = 10)
      AND fcv.concurrent_program_id = fcr.concurrent_program_id
      AND fcr.actual_completion_date IS NOT NULL
      AND fcr.actual_completion_date in ( SELECT max(fcr1.actual_completion_date)
                                          FROM apps.fnd_concurrent_programs_vl fcv1,apps.fnd_concurrent_requests fcr1
                                          WHERE user_concurrent_program_name IN ( SELECT fvv.description
                                                                                  FROM apps.fnd_lookup_types_vl ftv,
                                                                                       apps.fnd_lookup_values_vl fvv
                                                                                  WHERE ftv.lookup_type = fvv.lookup_type
                                                                                  AND ftv.lookup_type LIKE 'CRM_JOBS'
                                                                                  AND fvv.tag = 10)
                                        AND fcv1.concurrent_program_id = fcr1.concurrent_program_id
                                        AND fcr1.PHASE_CODE='C'
                                        AND fcr1.actual_completion_date IS NOT NULL
                                        GROUP BY fcr1.concurrent_program_id)
        )
         UNION
         (SELECT fcv.user_concurrent_program_name "PROGRAM_NAME",
                 fcr.request_id "LAST_RUN_REQUEST_ID",
                 TO_CHAR(fcr.actual_completion_date,' DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "LAST_RUNDATE" ,
                 DECODE(fcr.phase_code,
                                      'C','Completed',fcr.phase_code)||'/'||DECODE(fcr.status_code,
                                                                                                   'C', 'Normal',
                                                                                                   'D', 'Cancelled',
                                                                                                   'E','Errored',
                                                                                                   'F','Scheduled',
                                                                                                   'G', 'Warning',fcr.status_code) "RESULT"
          FROM apps.fnd_concurrent_programs_vl fcv,
               apps.fnd_concurrent_requests fcr
          WHERE fcv.concurrent_program_id = fcr.concurrent_program_id
          AND request_id IN (SELECT request_id
                             FROM apps.fnd_concurrent_programs_vl fcv,
                                  apps.fnd_concurrent_requests fcr
                             WHERE fcv.USER_CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_NAME IN (SELECT fvv.description
                                                                        FROM apps.fnd_lookup_types_vl ftv,
                                                                             apps.fnd_lookup_values_vl fvv
                                                                        WHERE ftv.lookup_type = fvv.lookup_type
                                                                        AND ftv.lookup_type LIKE 'CRM_JOBS'
                                                                        AND fvv.tag = 20)
                             AND fcv.concurrent_program_id = fcr.concurrent_program_id
                             AND fcr.actual_completion_date IS NOT NULL
                             AND 2>=(SELECT count(fcr1.request_id)
                                     FROM apps.fnd_concurrent_programs_vl fcv1,
                                          apps.fnd_concurrent_requests fcr1
                                     WHERE fcv1.USER_CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_NAME=fcv.USER_CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_NAME
                                     AND fcr1.actual_completion_date>=fcr.actual_completion_date
                                     AND fcv1.concurrent_program_id = fcr1.concurrent_program_id
                                     AND fcr1.PHASE_CODE='C'
                                     AND fcr1.actual_completion_date IS NOT NULL)
                             UNION
                             (SELECT request_id
                              FROM (SELECT request_id
                                    FROM apps.fnd_concurrent_programs_vl fcv,
                                         apps.fnd_concurrent_requests fcr
                                    WHERE USER_CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_NAME IN (SELECT fvv.description
                                                                           FROM apps.fnd_lookup_types_vl ftv,
                                                                                apps.fnd_lookup_values_vl fvv
                                                                           WHERE ftv.lookup_type = fvv.lookup_type
                                                                           AND ftv.lookup_type LIKE 'CRM_JOBS'
                                                                           AND fvv.tag = 40)
                                    AND fcv.concurrent_program_id = fcr.concurrent_program_id
                                    AND fcr.PHASE_CODE='C'
                                    AND fcr.actual_completion_date IS NOT NULL
                                    ORDER BY request_id desc
                                    )
                                    WHERE rownum<=4
                              )
                              )
          )
          UNION
          (
          SELECT fcr.description, fcr.request_id "LAST_RUN_REQUEST_ID",
          TO_CHAR (fcr.actual_completion_date,'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "LAST_RUNDATE",
          DECODE (fcr.phase_code,
                                 'C', 'Completed', fcr.phase_code)|| '/'|| DECODE (fcr.status_code,
                                                                                                   'C', 'Normal',
                                                                                                   'D', 'Cancelled',
                                                                                                   'E', 'Errored',
                                                                                                   'F', 'Scheduled',
                                                                                                   'G', 'Warning',
                                                                                                   fcr.status_code) "RESULT"
          FROM apps.fnd_concurrent_programs_vl fcv,
               apps.fnd_concurrent_requests fcr
          WHERE fcr.description LIKE 'JDSU SNT Customer Portal Extract Set'
          AND fcv.concurrent_program_id = fcr.concurrent_program_id
          AND fcr.actual_completion_date IS NOT NULL
          AND fcr.actual_completion_date IN (
                                             SELECT   MAX (fcr2.actual_completion_date)
                                             FROM apps.fnd_concurrent_programs_vl fcv2,
                                                  apps.fnd_concurrent_requests fcr2
                                             WHERE fcr2.description IN (SELECT fvv.description
                                                                        FROM apps.fnd_lookup_types_vl ftv,
                                                                             apps.fnd_lookup_values_vl fvv
                                                                        WHERE ftv.lookup_type = fvv.lookup_type
                                                                        AND ftv.lookup_type LIKE 'CRM_JOBS'
                                                                        AND fvv.tag = 5)
                                             AND fcv2.concurrent_program_id = fcr2.concurrent_program_id
                                             AND fcr2.PHASE_CODE='C'
                                             AND fcr2.actual_completion_date IS NOT NULL
                                             GROUP BY fcr2.concurrent_program_id)
            )
ORDER BY 1,2 DESC )
c);

BEGIN

   SELECT name
     INTO l_instance
     FROM v$database;

    l_From := 'wf'||lower(l_instance)||'@AtOracle.com';

    l_Subject := p_subject|| ' Status Card on '||to_char(l_run_date,'DD-Mon-YYYY')||'{'||l_instance||'}';


       l_Mail_Conn := utl_smtp.Open_Connection(l_Mail_Host, 25);
        utl_smtp.Helo(l_Mail_Conn, l_Mail_Host);
        utl_smtp.Mail(l_Mail_Conn, l_From);


    IF l_recipient_to_list IS NOT NULL THEN
       WHILE l_rp1 <> 0
           LOOP

           l_rp := instr(l_recipient_to_list,',',l_rp1);

              exit when l_rp=0;

           l_Recipient := substr(l_recipient_to_list,l_rp1,l_rp-l_rp1);

           utl_smtp.Rcpt(l_Mail_Conn,l_Recipient);

           l_rp1 :=l_rp+1;

           END LOOP;

           IF L_RP=0 THEN
           l_Recipient := substr(l_recipient_to_list,l_rp1);
           utl_smtp.Rcpt(l_Mail_Conn,l_Recipient);
           END IF;
      END IF;

         l_rp  :=1;
         l_rp1 :=1;

    IF l_recipient_cc_list IS NOT NULL THEN
       WHILE l_rp1 <> 0
           LOOP

           l_rp := instr(l_recipient_cc_list,',',l_rp1);

              exit when l_rp=0;

           l_Recipient := substr(l_recipient_cc_list,l_rp1,l_rp-l_rp1);

           utl_smtp.Rcpt(l_Mail_Conn,l_Recipient);

           l_rp1 :=l_rp+1;

           END LOOP;

           IF L_RP=0 THEN
           l_Recipient := substr(l_recipient_cc_list,l_rp1);
           utl_smtp.Rcpt(l_Mail_Conn,l_Recipient);
           END IF;
      END IF;




l_msg_body :=  l_msg_body
             || '<html>'
             || '<body>'
             || '<pre><font face="TimesNewRoman" size="2"><b><font color="#0000FF"></b></font></pre>'
             || '</body>'|| '</html>';

l_msg_body :=  l_msg_body
             ||'<table BORDER  WIDTH="100%"  BGCOLOR="#66FFFF" >
                <tr> 
                <td WIDTH=600 HEIGHT =100 ALIGN="CENTER"><b><font color="#000000">'||p_subject||'</strong></font></b></td>
                <td>
                <table BORDER=0.5 WIDTH="100%" BGCOLOR="#CCCCCC" > 
                <tr> <td> </td>   
                <td>
                <tr> <td BGCOLOR="#FFFF00">'
             ||'Yellow = Completed Warning'
             ||'</td></tr>
             <tr> <td> </td>   <td><tr> <td BGCOLOR="#FF0000">'
             ||'Red    = Completed Error'
             ||'</td><tr> <td BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF">'
             ||'White  = Completed Successfully  '
             ||'</td></tr><tr> <td> </td></tr></table><td></td></tr></table>'
             ;

l_msg_body :=  l_msg_body
             || '<table BORDER COLS=5 WIDTH="100%" BGCOLOR="#CCCCCC" ><tr><td WIDTH="10%" ALIGN="CENTER"><b><font color="#000000">S.no</strong></font></b></td>
                 <td WIDTH="40%" ALIGN="CENTER"><b><font color="#000000"><strong>Program Name</strong></font></b></td>
                 <td WIDTH="15%" ALIGN="CENTER"><b><font color="#000000"><strong>Last Run Request ID</strong></font></b></td>
                 <td WIDTH="20%" ALIGN="CENTER"><b><font color="#000000"><strong>Last Run Date</strong></font></b></td>
                 <td WIDTH="15%" ALIGN="CENTER"><b><font color="#000000"><strong>Result</strong></font></b></td> </tr>'
               ;

-- Daily --
 FOR i in cur_req_list_data
  LOOP

       IF i.result = 'Completed/Normal' then
        l_bg_colour := 'BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF"';
       ELSIF i.result = 'Completed/Warning' then
            j:=j+1;
          l_bg_colour := 'BGCOLOR="#FFFF00"';
       ELSIF i.result ='Completed/Errored' then
             j:=j+1;
          l_bg_colour := 'BGCOLOR="#FF0000"';
       END IF ;
       l_msg_body :=  l_msg_body
                    || '<tr BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" ><td WIDTH="10%" ALIGN="LEFT"><font color="#000000">'
                    ||replace(i.rownum,'!','')
                    ||'</font></td><td '
                    ||l_bg_colour
                    ||' WIDTH="40%"  ALIGN="LEFT"><font color="#000000"><strong>'
                    ||replace(i.program_name,'!','')
                    ||'</strong></font></td> <td '
                    ||l_bg_colour
                    ||' WIDTH="15%" ALIGN="LEFT"><font color="#000000"><strong>'
                    ||replace(i.LAST_RUN_REQUEST_ID,'!','')
                    ||'</strong></font></td><td '
                    ||l_bg_colour
                    ||' WIDTH="20%" ALIGN="LEFT"><font color="#000000"><strong>'
                    ||replace(i.LAST_RUNDATE,'!','')
                    ||'</strong></font></td><td '
                    ||l_bg_colour
                    ||' WIDTH="15%" ALIGN="LEFT"><font color="#000000"><strong>'
                    ||replace(i.RESULT,'!','')
                    ||'</strong></font></td></tr>'
                    ;

      l_bg_colour   := null;


      END LOOP;



      l_msg_body := l_msg_body||'</table>';

      IF j!=0 THEN

         l_msg_body :=  l_msg_body
                      ||'<br><table BORDER=0 COLS=1 WIDTH="100%" > <tr  ><td WIDTH=400 ALIGN="LEFT"><b>NOTE : <font color="#ff0000"> Few jobs Completed Error or Completed Warning </font></b></td></tr> <br></br>';
      END IF;

         l_signature :=  '<br><table BORDER=0 COLS=1 WIDTH="50%" > <tr  ><td WIDTH=400 ALIGN="LEFT"><font color="#555658"> Best Regards </strong></font></td></tr><tr  ><td WIDTH=400 ALIGN="LEFT"><b><font color="#555658">'
                       || p_signature1
                       ||'</strong></font></b></td></tr>';
      IF p_signature2 IS NOT NULL THEN
         l_signature :=  l_signature
                       ||'<tr  ><td WIDTH="50%" ALIGN="LEFT"><font color="#555658">'
                       || p_signature2
                       ||' </strong></font></td></tr>';
      END IF;
      IF p_signature3 IS NOT NULL THEN
         l_signature :=  l_signature
                       ||'<tr  ><td WIDTH="50%" ALIGN="LEFT"><font color="#555658">'
                       || p_signature3
                       ||' </strong></font></td></tr>';
      END IF;

      IF P_SIGNATURE4 IS NOT NULL THEN
         l_signature :=  l_signature
                       || '<tr  ><td WIDTH="50%" ALIGN="LEFT"><font color="#555658"> Team PDL: <u> <font color="#0000CC"> '
                       || p_signature4
                       ||' </u> </strong></font></td></tr>';
      END IF;

       l_msg_body := 'From: '      || l_From || l_crlf ||
                     'Subject: '   || l_Subject|| l_crlf ||
                     'To: '        || l_recipient_to_list || l_crlf ||
                     'CC: '        || l_recipient_cc_list || l_crlf ||
                     'Importance: '|| l_priority ||  l_crlf || l_msg_body||l_signature|| '';


       utl_smtp.data(l_Mail_Conn, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || l_crlf ||'Content-type: text/html' || l_crlf || l_msg_body);
       utl_smtp.Quit(l_Mail_Conn);
EXCEPTION
                     WHEN OTHERS THEN
                 fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.LOG,'This is the exception caught during data AND quit');
END;
```

Comment: I doubt anyone will be able to provide you advice based on this limited information.  Show some code.  Try to reduce it to a simple reproducible test case.

Comment: Is the same bug causing the question title to be in ALL CAPS?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: surely will do from the next time marc...!!...for time being want to know where it is gng wrong in that html tags...UTL_SMTP in plsql.. :(

Comment: There's so much code here you can't format it all at once ;-)

Comment: yeah DCookie itz true but have to do some times as the code we write must be readabe ;)

Comment: the cursor is fetching the data rightly...with the supplied parameters to the procedure...the procedure is mailing the output to the recepients..but the problem is..the mail body contains some exclamatory marks in b/w...also in the values being fetched by the cursor also exclamatory marks are being displayed..donno wat to do...some 1 help me

Comment: 'the cursor is fetching the data rightly' but '...cursor also exclamatory marks are being displayed'. So the underlying data has the exclamation marks, and it's nothing really to do with mail? Is your question really why the `replace(i.rownum,'!','')` etc. don't seem to be working? For a start I'd move the `replace()` into the cursor to see if it still has them in the output. And if so I'd isolate one result and dump it to see what it's actually got - maybe chr(289) instead of chr(33), or a character set issue...

Answer (score 6):

[RFC 821](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc821.html) which specifies the SMTP protocol specifies that the maximum length of a line of text is 1000 characters including the CRLF.

> text line
>
> The maximum total length of a text line including the
>    is 1000 characters (but not counting the leading
>   dot duplicated for transparency).

I don't see anywhere in your code that you are adding CRLF's to your text so it appears that you are trying to generate a single line of text that is well in excess of 1000 characters.  The exclamation points you seeing are likely the result of your SMTP server adding CRLF's every 1000 characters or so in order to make your message valid.  If you added CRLF's yourself instead so that no line was more than 1000 characters, the exclamation points should go away.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue using UTL_SMTP.write_data to write attachment data and subsequently receiving duplicate decimal points in the data. This solution also works for that scenario because adding UTL_TCP.crlf to the data every 900 (less than 1000) characters stopped it from happening.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the CRLF character reduced the length of each line, regardless of the length of the body and <br/> tag.

For my particular case I have a variable to hold the <br/> tag and appending the UTL_TCP.CRLF, i.e.,  v_endline VARCHAR2 (100) := '<br/>' || UTL_TCP.CRLF; solved my issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think adding new empty lines in the html tags will resolve the issue. just add the appropriate tags to get a new space such that the message you are printing will not be a 1000 character one as a whole but will be reduced in length